# Create parent child from flat array php

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i have some simple array and want build child and parent.

```
$arr = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );

function fre( $arr ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
        echo '-' . $arr[$i];
        $i++;
    }

}

echo fre($arr);
```

I want final result like this:

```
a
-b
--c
```

Thank you.

Comment: No real need to create a outer variable as a counter, if you use a for-each on a indexed array, the `key` is it's index and the `value` is the value of the given index. You are using the foreach as a for-loop in every aspect except actually using a for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple cycle:

```
$prefix = "";

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo $prefix.$value."\n";
    $prefix .= "-";
}
```